# Where to know what version of native Linux command got the specific feature?

Tags: command-history

I have `lscpu` Linux command with specific attribute `-J` allows to output in JSON format.

I want to use the command at hundreds of hosts with different Linux distros to get the CPU information. I want to do it automatically.

Sometime ago I got warning that `-J` attribute is new command feature and it can be off at older Linux distros.

I want to suggest how many hosts would support that feature. What docs should I use to know WHEN `-J` of lscpu was included?

All web pages describes the command has only current its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code for lscpu can be found at https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commits/master/sys-utils/lscpu.c.  Looking at the history it looks like the JSON stuff was first introduced around 3 years ago.